# How to trace https request/response bodies in System.Net

Tags: .net, logging, trace

It is possible to trace http message bodies in addition to headers when dealing with System.Net.Sockets?

I'm researching Google.Apis.Auth library and want to know what exactly is sends to and receives from their HTTPS server (in decrypted form).

My switches section in app.config looks like

```
<switches>
  <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
  <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose"/>
  <add name="System.Net.Http" value="Verbose"/>
  <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
  <add name="System.Net.WebSockets" value="Verbose"/>
</switches>
```

still I'm getting only http headers, not bodies.

Comment: Check out fiddlercore

Comment: I thought it's possible without using a profiler but looks like it's not Thanks.